# TFS - Could not find the SonarQube issue report

Tags: tfs, sonarqube, azure-devops

I'm using TFS 2017 and SonarQube <s>5.6.2</s> <s>5.6.4</s> 6.2.

I'm trying to setup SonarQube integration into pull requests. On pull requests that don't appear to have any issues the sonarqube analysis runs fine. It looks like it only fails when there are issues found and it tries to read the `sonar-report.json` to post the issues to the pull request. I'm receiving the following error on builds that appear to find issues:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
EXECUTION SUCCESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 5:25.577s
Final Memory: 56M/600M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
The SonarQube Scanner has finished
Creating a summary markdown file...
Analysis results: http://somedomain:9000/dashboard/index/CP
Post-processing succeeded.
Fetching code analysis issues and posting them to the PR...
System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Could not find the SonarQube issue report at D:\agent2-TFS-Build01\_work\13\.sonarqube\out\.sonar\sonar-report.json. Unable to post issues to the PR. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find the SonarQube issue report at D:\agent2-TFS-Build01\_work\13\.sonarqube\out\.sonar\sonar-report.json. Unable to post issues to the PR.
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
 at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineBase.Invoke(IEnumerable input)
 at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.ConstructPipelineAndDoWork(Runspace rs, Boolean performSyncInvoke)
 at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.CreateRunspaceIfNeededAndDoWork(Runspace rsToUse, Boolean isSync)
 at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvokeHelper[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
 at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvoke[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
 at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Handlers.PowerShellHandler.Execute(ITaskContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Int32 timeoutInMinutes)
 at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Worker.JobRunner.RunTask(ITaskContext context, TaskWrapper task, CancellationTokenSource tokenSource)
```

As far as I can tell, there is no way to configure the location of this report. One thing I read was that if you aren't failing the build on quality gate failures then you should also not enable the option to include full analysis report in the build summary. There were no specifics on why this is the case. I currently have the option to include the report enabled. Could this be the cause of my problem? We are not failing builds on quality gate failures yet because I was trying to give devs some time to adjust to the changes. Anyone know what's going on here? Here is a screenshot of my prepare analysis settings. 
[image]

You can find a copy of the logs for the end analysis step [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5teah2HdC86M3JYSUpzTjkwSWs/view?usp=sharing). I've retracted the domain and username. Everything else in the log is left untouched.

Edit 1/19:

Since I don't have fail on quality gate failure enabled I am not getting an error message if the build does fail the quality gate. I'm receiving the error message that I posted above about the `sonar-report.json` missing. Here is what I am seeing for pull requests with zero issues.

```
Fetching code analysis issues and posting them to the PR...
SonarQube found 0 issues out of which 0 are new
True
Processing 0 new messages
No new messages were posted
Uploading the legacy summary report. The new report is not uploaded if not enabled, if the SonarQube server version is 5.2 or lower or if the build was triggered by a pull request
The build was not set to fail if the associated quality gate fails.
```

This is why I think it only happens on builds that do have some issues to post to the PR. When is the `sonar-report.json` that it's looking for supposed to be written? I looked in the workspace on the build server and the file is definitely not there.

**Edit 1/30/17:**

Here is some additional info that may help figure out what it is. Currently I have 26 projects that run a SQ analysis on both PR and CI builds. All CI builds are working as expected. 24/26 PR builds are working as expected. The only two builds that are failing are both webapp projects. One of them is made up of C#, TypeScript, and JavaScript. The other is C#, VB, TypeScript, and Javascript. All the projects that are succeeding are strictly C# applications. What I have noticed is that on all of the C# applications I see a log message similar to this:

```
INFO: Performing issue tracking
INFO: 1033/1033 components tracked
INFO: Export issues to D:\agent2-TFS-Build01\_work\35\.sonarqube\out\.sonar\sonar-report.json
INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL
```

This little `Export` bit is missing from the failed builds. Here is a log snippet from one of the failed PR builds. I would expect the logs to be in somewhat similar order but the `Export issues to ...` section is missing. Also it looks like it's uploading a full analysis report even though this is a PR build:

```
INFO: Analysis report generated in 2672ms, dir size=10 MB
INFO: Analysis reports compressed in 2750ms, zip size=4 MB
INFO: Analysis report uploaded in 583ms
INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://~:9000/dashboard/index/AppName
```

I'm getting tons of `Missing blame information for the following files: [long list of files]` errors during the analysis for the JS files that are being generated by the TypeScript compiler. I don't know if those errors would have anything to do with why this is failing but it's the only errors I see in the logs for that build step.

So, now I guess the problem to figure out is why are the issues for the two web app projects not being exported to the `sonar-report.json`. As you can see in the following log messages it appears that both projects are being started as PR builds with analysis mode set to `issues` and export path set to `sonar-report.json` but by the time the scan is done it skips the export step.

```
##[debug]Calling InvokeGetRestMethod "/api/server/version" 
##[debug]Variable read: MSBuild.SonarQube.HostUrl = http://somedomain:9000/
##[debug]Variable read: MSBuild.SonarQube.ServerUsername = ********
##[debug]Variable read: MSBuild.SonarQube.ServerPassword = 
##[debug]GET http://somedomain:9000/api/server/version with 0-byte payload
##[debug]received 3-byte response of content type text/html;charset=utf-8
##[debug]/d:sonar.ts.lcov.reportPath="C:\TFS-Build02-Agent2\_work\11\s\Source\AppName.Web\CodeCoverage\lcov\lcov.info" /d:sonar.ts.tslintconfigpath="C:\TFS-Build02-Agent2\_work\11\s\Source\AppName.Web\tslint.json" /d:sonar.ts.tslintruledir="C:\TFS-Build02-Agent2\_work\11\s\Source\AppName.Web\tslint-rules\" /d:sonar.ts.tslintpath="C:\TFS-Build02-Agent2\_work\11\s\Source\AppName.Web\node_modules\tslint\bin\tslint" /d:sonar.analysis.mode=issues /d:sonar.report.export.path=sonar-report.json
```

And the second one that is failing:

```
##[debug]Calling InvokeGetRestMethod "/api/server/version" 
##[debug]Variable read: MSBuild.SonarQube.HostUrl = http://somedomain:9000/
##[debug]Variable read: MSBuild.SonarQube.ServerUsername = ********
##[debug]Variable read: MSBuild.SonarQube.ServerPassword = 
##[debug]GET http://somedomain:9000/api/server/version with 0-byte payload
##[debug]received 3-byte response of content type text/html;charset=utf-8
##[debug]/d:sonar.ts.lcov.reportpath="D:\agent2-TFS-Build01\_work\13\s\Source\AppName.WebApp\CodeCoverage\lcov\lcov.info" /d:sonar.ts.tslintconfigpath="D:\agent2-TFS-Build01\_work\13\s\Source\AppName.WebApp\tslint.json" /d:sonar.ts.tslintruledir="D:\agent2-TFS-Build01\_work\13\s\Source\AppName.WebApp\tslint-rules\" /d:sonar.ts.tslintpath="D:\agent2-TFS-Build01\_work\13\s\Source\AppName.WebApp\node_modules\tslint" /d:sonar.analysis.mode=issues /d:sonar.report.export.path=sonar-report.json
```

Comment: Setting option "Fail the build on quality gate failure" causes the “SonarQube for MSBuild – End Analysis” task step to fail if the quality gate associated with the project fails; which, in turn, causes the entire build to fail and generate a SonarQube quality gate error message. Do you get such error? Could you share you build definition?

Comment: @Cece I've updated my question with some additional details. I don't feel comfortable sharing the entire build definition. I tried exporting as PDF but I don't have a good way to edit PDFs and there is some info I in there I can't share for security reasons. Tried editing in Word but everything was jumbled around. Is there something in particular you are looking for?

Comment: Just kidding, I've retracted anything that was a security concern from this document.Thanks for taking a look. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5teah2HdC86REZVcV85ZFZEQmM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Just verified that it's working for builds of different projects. It's just this specific build that is failing. The project associated with this build is pretty large. Could that have anything to do with it?

Comment: It seems your issue is not related to TFS, but your project. Are you able to get a successful SonarQube analysis for this project if you don't use PR build?

Comment: Yes, the full analysis completes successfully on a CI build.

Comment: How about creating a new PR in this repo?

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't matter. All PR builds for this project fail with the `Could not find the SonarQube issue report` error I mentioned above. ALL of them. We have multiple PR builds on any given day and they are all failing with this error. The only successful analysis is on a merge to master when the full analysis runs.

Comment: Do you have SonarQube 6.0 server? What's the result if you are using SonarQube 6.0?

Comment: I just upgraded to SQ 6.2 over the weekend and I'm still experiencing this issue.

Comment: I've added some more info that may help figure out what is happening under the `Edit 1/30/2017` section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally had some time to circle back around to figuring out this problem. It appears that the SonarQube VSTS task doesn't export the issues report if it encounters an error during the end analysis step. I went through the build logs and made sure to exclude any of the js files that are generated by the typescript compiler. This helped to get rid of the many `missing blame information` errors that were happening. Once I had those files excluded from analysis I updated the [SonarTsPlugin](https://github.com/Pablissimo/SonarTsPlugin/releases) to the latest version along with all the associated build variables and PR integration started working again.

I know this worked because I no longer see the `RuntimeException: Could not find the SonarQube issue report` error. Now I see this in the logs:

```
SonarQube found 9264 issues out of which 102 are new
Processing 102 new messages
102 message(s) were filtered because they do not belong to files that were changed in this PR
```

If you are experiencing a problem like this I suggest you look at fixing any build errors you see in the logs for the end analysis step. Once I had them all resolved it started working as intended.